# Select Filtered with LINQ and EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a class like this, which is derived from a database with EF (my database contains all records from this class):

```
public class Products
{
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public string owner { get; set; }
    public string buyer { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> After { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> Before { get; set; }
}
```

Now, on my web form users can specify each property in free text boxes and I want to search in the database entity, based on these properties. The user can decide to fill all properties, or may be just two of them. How do I create the .select in EF?

Any help welcome!

BR,
Ronald

Comment: What do you have that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Products.GetAllProducts().Where(x=>(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtColor.Text) || x.color ==txtColor.Text) && 
                                             (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSize) || x.size ==  txtSize.Text)  &&
                                             --- Same as other fields
                                            ).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Thanks, well, it's now a combination of answers:  .Where(x => (x.Color.StartsWith(txtbx_color)) 
                                    && (x.Size.StartsWith(txtbx_Size) 
                                    && x.owner.StartsWith(txtbx_owner)
and so on, guess you can use startswith or contains just alike in my case. Is contains kinda like a SQL 'like' statement?

Comment: you are going to filter data by enter values in respective controls by user ....but if you want search  "like sql statement" then you can use startwith no issue...it will filter on statwith value ...x.color.StartsWith(txtColor.Text)

Answer (score 0):

```
Db.Products
.Where(p=>string.IsNullOrEmty(colorTexBox.Text) || p.color==colorTexBox.Text)
.Where(p=>check other property...)
.
.
.AsEnumerable()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .Contains method:

```
private bool IsMatch(string value, string searchCriteria)
{
   if(searchCriteria == null || value == null) return true;   
   return value.ToUpper().Contains(searchCriteria.ToUpper());
}

public Products FindProducts(string color, string size, string comment, string owner, string buyer, datetime? after, datetime? before)    
{
    using(MyDbContext cont = new MyDbContext())
    {
        return cont.Products.Where((p) =>
        {
           return IsMatch(p. color, color) && IsMatch(p.size, size) && 
           IsMatch(p.comment, comment) && IsMatch(p.owner, owner) && 
           IsMatch(p.buter, buyer);  // add your logic for dates here
        });
    }   
}
```

Comment: I like this approach as well!